# framework not found QGLViewer

Tags: macos, qt, frameworks, makefile

I am trying to install QGLViewer. When I compile it with QTcreator everything goes well, but when I try to build one of its examples, it gives me this error:

framework not found QGLViewer

I know that it is installed, because when I do

```
otool -D /Users/sara/Library/Frameworks/QGLViewer.framework/Versions/Current/QGLViewer
```

the response is `QGLViewer`

I really want this library to work. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug. It was fixed in the last update.

http://www.libqglviewer.com/changeLog.html

Comment: Great, now add a reference to your claim.